# AngularJS trigger a function outside App scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a code that looks like this:

```
<div id="ng-div" ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="dataController">
        //... stuff that populates $scope.data
        <button id="submit1" ng-click="processData()">Quote</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('dataController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.data = [];

        $scope.processData = function(jobs) {
            console.log($scope.data);
        };
    }]);

</script>


<button id="submit2">Quote (Outside scope)</button>
```

Due to legacy/design limitations, I need to have the Quote button to be somewhere else (which is outside the ng-app div/scope), for example the "submit2" button.

How can I trigger the processData() function using vanilla/jquery?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" id="myCtrl">
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = function(){
     alert('Hii from controller');
    }
});

function myFunction() {
      angular.element(document.getElementById('myCtrl')).scope().test();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The thing is, I cannot do that, as the ng-app is part of an SPA frame, but I need to reuse a global Jquery button generator script to keep them consistent across the site.